# Custom Errors in ASP.net MVC6

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, custom-exceptions

I have created an ASP.net 5 MVC6 project and added the following:

```
  app.UseStatusCodePages();
```

inside my Configure method. If I run the application, open my web browser and navigate to the following URL:

http://localhost:33358/ReallyLongInvalidPathReallyLongInvalidPathReallyLongInvalidPathReallyLongInvalidPathReallyLongInvalidPathReallyLongInvalidPathReallyLongInvalidPathReallyLongInvalidPath

ASP Displays a 404 error message which is the expected behavior. If I navigate to an even longer invalid URL such as:

http://localhost:33358/EvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPath

I now get the following:

Bad Request - Invalid URL

If you navigate to the equivalent [MSDN](http://msdn.com/EvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPath) URL you get the same result. However If you navigate to the equivalent [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/EvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPathEvenLongerInvalidPath) URL it is somehow handled. How are they handling this? and how can this be done in ASP.net MVC6?

Answer (score 0):

Are you getting a 404.15  ? it might be that the query string length is too long for IIS . Check this https://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/security/requestfiltering/requestlimits

Try changing the maxQueryString attribute in thr requestLimits section in web.config to see if it helps.

Comment: Nope. I am getting the same error as when clicking on the MSDN link.

Comment: I am not sure if the sub status code information is shown directly on the error page.

There are ways to redirect to different pages based on the sub status code. But i am not sure if these configurations work in MVC 6 ( http://www.iis.net/learn/troubleshoot/diagnosing-http-errors/how-to-use-http-detailed-errors-in-iis ). The work for this may not have been finished yet.

Comment: I am pretty sure that its not even getting that far. Similar to when visiting a URL such as: http://stackoverflow.com/%